# SOAP API - Parsing WSDL Could not load from HTTP- 401 Authorization Required

Tags: magento-enterprise, api, wsdl

(I believe this question is not quite a duplicate of the other Parsing WSDL questions, as I'm receiving a `401 Authorization Required` error)

Every so often on Magento 1.13.1.0 when connecting to my soap API I'll receive the following error

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1"
```

I dug into the apache error log and pulled this out

```
[Tue Jan 20 14:12:14 2015] [error] [client 192.168.200.11] PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n in /var/www/vhosts/magesite/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 762
[Tue Jan 20 14:12:14 2015] [error] [client 192.168.200.11] PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1" in /var/www/vhosts/magesite/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 762
[Tue Jan 20 14:12:14 2015] [error] [client 192.168.200.11] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1"\n in /var/www/vhosts/magesite/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 762
```

The problem is that this error is inconsistent, some times I am able to connect without issue and others I receive this error.

I created the following script to test the issue:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1';
echo "\nConnecting to\n$url\n";

for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
    /** @var SoapClient $client */
    $client = new SoapClient($url);
    echo $i."\t";
    try {
        echo $client->login('username', 'key')."\n";
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo substr($e->getMessage(), 0, 50)."\n";
    }
    unset($client);
}
```

The output of which looks like:

```
Connecting to
http://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1
0   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
1   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
2   aa58f99c61e58e7f2366632886665352
3   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
4   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
5   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
6   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
7   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
8   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http
```

You can see that on run #2 we login successfully, making this a weird intermittent issue.

What is even weirder, is when I enable WSDL cache (`System -> Configuration -> Magento Core API -> Enable WSDL Cache`) it seems to fix the problem completley. I never receive the error again, and the program output looks like:

```
Connecting to
http://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl=1
0   4c89a4cb0ccc8d1ed8310067cde6bdaf
1   415bf4a7f89e9df66366c20c081569ef
2   6d339eb604244fe9a6f1df64aebd07ce
3   fa940c6b5561b5d248e0c458e3c68630
4   453c8a33c21404cba98a08c051852ba3
5   01f6a34924b7c7a3d80b2d8b66f6f31e
6   85baa98accdc480fd4cfda41c8ca3f50
7   931fa7574600f22d895fb47233fa91ce
8   72c40849df54d96e4af818a5e1e2ccd3
```

Can anyone shed any light on the issue, how is WSDL cache supressing this auth error, and what the correct fix might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah fun stuff.

This problem was occurring between two load balanced servers.

When magento tried to access itself by `hostname` one server was actually going to the other server, causing the `401 unauthorized`.

We updated the hosts file so that each server knew to go to itself and not the other, and the weird problems disappeared.

I'm not quire sure why enabling WSDL cache fixed it, but extra caching sounds good so I'm going to leave it on.